# How to scroll 360 to the center of the svg group?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I put a demo on [Codepen](http://%20https://codepen.io/untca/pen/NeyroK?editors=1100)

I have a gear there, and I want it to spin relative to its centers (like wheeled vehicles) while sitting behind a piece of paper, but when I wrote CSS properties like a wheel to get it spinning relative to the central SVG, tell me how to fix the transform-origin property just for the gear so that it is in place and just spinning?

Answer (score 2):

try this
1) If you want to transform-origin with respect to your element you should use transform-box:fill-box first   as

```
#wheel
{ 
  .....   
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

2)this can be used if you want it to be relative to the parent svg. In this you have to adjust the value to find the exact position

```
#wheel{
   ....
   ....
   transform-origin: 29% 49%;
}
```